# Specifying the column name in a DolphinDB SQL query at runtime

Tags: dolphindb

In DolphinDB, I would like to write a function that takes a table `t` and a string `colName` as arguments and run a SQL query according to `t` and `colName`. My code is like this:

```
def doQuery(t, colName) {
    return select colName from t
}
```

But this function would return a table containing only one element `colName` whatever arguments I gave.

For example, when I ran

```
t = table(1..5 as col0)
doQuery(t, `col0)
```

What I expected was the column `col0` containing elements `1`, `2`, `3`, `4` and `5`, while what I got was

```
colName
-------
col0
```

I wonder what's wrong with my code.

Answer (score 0):

In a sql statement, one has to explicitly write down the column names in select clause. That is the rule for almost all databases including DolphinDB. In your case, the column name is dynamically passed by a function argument. That is, you can't specify the column when you write the code (sql query). However, DolphinDB offers meta-programming technology for you to solve the exact problem.

```
def doQuery(t, colName) {
    return sql(sqlCol(colName), t).eval()
}
```

http://www.dolphindb.com/help/index.html?Metaprogramming.html