# How to use a variable as a column name in DolphinDB?

Tags: sql, dolphindb

To simplify my question: start with the following table in DolphinDB:

```
t=table(1 2 3 as x, 4 5 6 as y)
```

I would like to select a column from the table, but I prefer to assign the column to choose in a separate statement. I tried the following:

```
colName= x
select colName from t
```

and

```
colName="x"
select colName from t
```

neither works. I am sure there is a way to do this in DolphinDB. Could someone point out where to look at in the manual? Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Specifying the column name in a DolphinDB SQL query at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55916314/specifying-the-column-name-in-a-dolphindb-sql-query-at-runtime)

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the part about metaprogramming in DolphinDB's manual:

https://www.dolphindb.com/help/Metaprogramming.html

For your question, try this:

```
colName= "x"
sql(select=sqlCol(colName), from=t).eval()
```